Do the hadith gradings include a flat-lined percentage?
What do the gradings of hadith actually mean? The terms sound, fair, and weak are a bit ambiguous to me. Is there a sort of flat-lined percentage for each grading level? For example, sahih would have an 100% chance of being authentic, and hasan would be considered an 80% of being authentic, and daif would be considered an 60% chance of being authentic. Do such flat-lined percentages occur within the hadith sciences, or do things just not operate within a vacuum like this?
